# Which aircraft would be effective in medieval times?

Tags: alternate-reality

Based slightly off the anime [GATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_(novel_series)#Anime), if I had excess to modern military technology and an army to operate them in medieval times like the anime, which aircraft would be better suited to destroy a city?lets say the modern army already has a base built at the medieval land and they have a good supply line. The only thing to worry about now is to figure out which aircraft out of the two would be most effective to be used by the army

Comment: Which one of those uses fuel you'd have access to?

Comment: For anything, the concept of "better suited" strongly depends on the use case. A knife can be better suited at slicing meat, but for eating a soup is quite useless. Unless you define the use case, there is no way to answer this question

Comment: Effective in what sense? The number of people they can kill? Travelling long distance quickly? Transporting and deploying troops in the battlefield? Flying over and providing recognisance? Also, what are the requirements for a ‘good’ answer? I think this may be closed for being too oppinion based or for being unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: You need to make the question standalone: Non one should be required to look up the anime you reference, so you'd need to make some things clear: must the aircraft be refuelled, landed, repaired, ertc in medieval setting (i.e. no runway...)? What is the aircraft supposed to accomplish? Will it need to destroy things randomly, or be a reconnaissance craft, or be the support of some troops (what kind, what mission?)? Will there be more than one? What range and mission-times are required? Will there be other high tech stuff on the side of the opposition? ...?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen the anime, but I would argue the biggest problem would be fuel and ammunition and spare parts (and to an lesser extent lubricating oil). They should pick the most primitive planes they can find, a helicopter is waaaay to complicated to use in medieval times. I would suggest World War 1 fighter planes, or maybe at most a World War 2 (propeller) fighter plane. A WW1 fighter can probably run on simple  vegetable oil or alcohol and they can even fix broken wooden wings. They can drop primitive medieval grenades or even make ammunition for the fighters gun.

Answer (score 2):

Given that a [fighter jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighter_aircraft) is mainly built to attack other aircraft while an [attack helicopter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_helicopter) is mainly built to attack ground targets, the attack helicopter is the obviously correct answer.

A factor is available fuel, unless the army has large reserves of modern fuel. Many helicopters use diesel oil, which might be easier to produce than jet fuel. It might even be possible to produce [biodiesel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biodiesel) from local farm products.

Answer (score 1):

How many other airplanes you need to FIGHT in the air in those times?
Or do you would need to ATTACK something? Like a castle, army or similar?

Not to mentions that for helicopter to operate you need a patch of land without trees slightly bigger than the size of rotors. For a Jet you need a large airstrip that would be flat and strong enough for a jet to take off.